# Coldfusion 11 AJAX cflayout behavior

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I have some applications developed on older CF versions (9&10) and in anticipation of a hosting system migrating to CF11 and started doing some testing with a CF development platform on Windows 8 with Apache 2.4.  I have found that in CF11 pages using cflayout and cflayoutarea does not work correctly when collapsed with javascript:ColdFusion.Layout.collapseArea.

Firebug does flag an error in the CF javascript.  Wondering if anyone else has seen a problem like this and if there is a circumvention I could use to get this working.

A very simple example (complements of the Chapter 2 cflayout example demonstrated in Dan Short's video on Ajax & Coldfusion) fails as well on CF11 but works in CF9 & CF10.

main.cfm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<cflayout name="borderLayout" type="border" fittowindow="true">
    <cflayoutarea name="header" position="top" size="75">This is the header<br />
    <a href="javascript:ColdFusion.Layout.collapseArea('borderLayout', 'left');">Collapse Left Column</a><br>
    </cflayoutarea>
    <cflayoutarea name="centerColumn" position="center" source="content.cfm?pageName=Header 1" />
    <cflayoutarea name="rightColumn" position="right" style="width: 100px;">This is the right column</cflayoutarea>
    <cflayoutarea name="leftColumn" position="left" title="Left Column" style="width: 250px;" collapsible="true" splitter="true" minsize="200">
        This is the left column<br />
        <a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('content.cfm?pagename=Header 2', 'centerColumn');">Load Header 2</a>
    </cflayoutarea>
    <cflayoutarea name="footer" position="bottom">This is a footer &copy; 2010</cflayoutarea>
</cflayout>
</body>
</html>
```

content.cfm

```
<cfsilent>
    <cfparam name="URL.pageName" default="Default header" />
</cfsilent>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<cfoutput><h2>#URL.pageName#</h2></cfoutput>
<p>This is the text content from content.cfm</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Also, you might want to seriously consider NOT using `cflayout`. The UI functionality in ColdFusion is notoriously poor in its implementation and limitations.

Comment: Edit the question and add the code there. it is unreadable in comments.

Comment: @user3922846 - Thanks for moving the code into the question. Since the two comments are now redundant, may as well delete them.